# Firebase Function not giving Function URL

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am creating my first firebase function app and I was going/following through [this tutorial/repo](https://github.com/jthegedus/firebase-gcp-examples/tree/master/fb-functions-express)

So what I did was in my main file Index.js (inside functions folder)

```
const app = express();
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const authRoutes = require("./src/routes/auth.js");
const meetupRoutes = require("./src/routes/meetup.js");
const eventbriteRoutes = require("./src/routes/eventbrite.js");
const nonMiddleWareRoutes = require("./src/routes/nonMiddleware.js");

app.use("/", nonMiddleWareRoutes);
app.use("/auth", authRoutes);
app.use("/meetup", meetupRoutes);
app.use("/eventbrite", eventbriteRoutes);

const api = functions.https.onRequest(app);

module.exports = {
  api
};
```

now moving back to the root folder we have `firebase.json` which just contains this

```
{}
```

and `.firebaserc`

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "functions-firebase-2312"
  }
}
```

Now, Whenever I do `firebase deploy`, it logs this in terminal

```
=== Deploying to 'functions-firebase-2312'...

i  deploying functions 
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled... 
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled 
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading... 
i  functions: packaged functions (60.3 KB) for uploading 
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully 
i  functions: updating Node.js 8 function api(us-central1)... 
✔  functions[api(us-central1)]: Successful update operation. 

✔  Deploy complete!

Please note that it can take up to 30 seconds for your updated functions to propagate.

Project Console: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/functions-firebase-2312/overview
```

but does not give me the url for the function.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will be given a URL the first time you deploy a function.  After that, you can go to the Firebase console to see the URL in the [Functions dashboard](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/functions/list).  They appear in rather small letters.